# Hadoop Command Permissions

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, permissions, root, delete-file

I have a file called example.txt inside my hdfs user/$USER_NAME folder. All I want to do is delete it using hadoop fs command. Thus:

```
hadoop fs -rm example.txt
```

When I run this however I get AccessControlException. Now if I run this in root mode it just operates on /user/example.txt. However I want it to operate on /user/$USER_NAME/example.txt. Any ideas on how to circumvent this issue. All suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

use below command.

```
hadoop dfs -rmr example.txt
```

Comment: isn't this deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

```
   hadoop fs -rm $USER_NAME/example.txt
```